# preflight check with SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress using a zero IPv6 address

Tags: ios, ipv6, reachability

I have a library that mimics Apple's own [Reachability.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Reachability_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_9) and its method reachabilityForInternetConnection to do a preflight check like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in zeroSockaddrin;
bzero(&zeroSockaddrin, sizeof(zeroSockaddrin));
zeroSockaddrin.sin_len = sizeof(zeroSockaddrin);
zeroSockaddrin.sin_family = AF_INET;

SCNetworkReachabilityRef networkReachabilityRef = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(allocator, (const struct sockaddr *)&zeroSockaddrin);

SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags = 0;
SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(networkReachabilityRef, &flags);
```

Now I'm trying to comply with Apple's new guideline to support IPv6 only networks.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW25

According to the above, I should

- Avoid preflighting network reachability
- Use SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName instead of SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress.

However For backward-compatibility reasons I would like to keep my preflight check, and I'd also like to keep using SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress to avoid the lag introduced by the DNS lookup of SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName.  So I simply changed the sockaddr_in to sockaddr_in6 like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 zeroSockaddrin;
bzero(&zeroSockaddrin, sizeof(zeroSockaddrin));
zeroSockaddrin.sin6_len = sizeof(zeroSockaddrin);
zeroSockaddrin.sin6_family = AF_INET6;

SCNetworkReachabilityRef networkReachabilityRef = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(allocator, (const struct sockaddr *)&zeroSockaddrin);

SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags = 0;
SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(networkReachabilityRef, &flags);
```

If I do this then I would only get 0 in "flags" regardless of whether my device is already connected via 4G or wifi.

I tried replacing sockaddr_in6 with sockaddr_storage - same results.  It seems like I can only get valid SCNetworkReachabilityFlags via using sockaddr_in or by using SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName with a proper host name.

Is there any reason why I'm not getting correct SCNetworkReachabilityFlags with an zero IPv6 address?

Comment: By zero IPv6 address, do you mean `::` the Unspecified Address? According to [RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture](RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture), "_The unspecified address must not be used as the destination address of IPv6 packets or in IPv6 Routing headers. An IPv6 packet with a source address of unspecified must never be forwarded by an IPv6 router._"

Comment: Yes I am getting :: in the address part of zeroSockaddrin in the code above.  That seems strong enough of a reason to me!